# Dynamic php rows gives values of 1st row only to javascript function when each row has its own dynamic values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have been toying with this for a while now and i can not get each row to send its specific values that are displayed to a javascript function only the 1st rows values are sent no matter which row is clicked?

I need to send the values for each specific row dependng on the results of the mysql result.

Below is the code that i have which only sends the values of the 1st row.

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';

$records = array();

$result = ("(SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25)ORDER BY id ASC");
$results = ($db->query($result));

if($results->num_rows){
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $results->free();
}

if(!count($records)){
    echo 'no records';
}else{
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php
    foreach ($records as $r){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="modOptions" onclick="modOptions()"><?php echo escape($r->sender); ?></div></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->message); ?></td>

            <input type="hidden" id="modOptionsIp" value="<?php echo escape($r->ip); ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="modOptionsSender" value="<?php echo escape($r->sender); ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="modOptionsMessage" value="<?php echo escape($r->message); ?>"/>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

It displays everything ok just doesnt give each row its specific values

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it is part of the problem or not, but with this code you will have several DIVs with the same ID `modOptions`

Comment: @philipe its ok thanks, nikola answered with a solution i just cant accept it as correct yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the js modOptions function so it can take parameters

```
function modOptions(ip, sender, message) {
    //ip sender and message are from the row you clicked on
}
```

and render the onclick like this:

```
onclick="modOptions('<?php echo escape($r->ip); ?>', '<?php echo escape($r->sender); ?>', '<?php echo escape($r->message); ?>' );"
```

those hidden fields you have now are useless

Comment: thanks! i had been toying this for ages with no luck :)